# Нужно обратиться к боту в телеграмм по ссылке

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, link

Когда переходят по ссылке на бота, нужно чтобы сразу отправилось сообщение боту, через ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Такое реализовать в Telegram не получится — API не позволяет принудительную отправку сообщения от имени пользователя при переходе по ссылке. Для этого пользователю всё же придётся нажать кнопку «Начать».